# elFinder issues. Undefined is not a function error when trying to copy file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, elfinder

I'm trying to implement [elFinder file manager](http://elfinder.org/).

This is what I've done.
Included  files:

```
    $arr_css = array(
              "main.css",
              "jquery-ui.css",
              "elfinder.min.css",
               "theme.css"
              );
    $arr_js = array(
               "jquery.js",
               "main.js",
               "jquery-ui.js",
               "elfinder.min.js",
               "elfinder.ru.js"
               );
```

(main.js and main.css are arrays used to create `<link rel='stylesheet'>` and `<script type='text/javascript'>`)

In my main page there is a

```
<div id='fileStructure'>
    <div id="elfinder"> </div>
</div>
```

which I use to initialize elfinder:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
        lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
        url : '/radio/elfinder-2.0-rc1/php/connector.php'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
    }).elfinder('instance');            
});
```

[image]

This is, what I have now. It looks fine, I can create directories, files, can upload them. But when I try to copy it it says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionelfinder.min.js:2841 elFinder.commands.copy.execelfinder.min.js:1746 (anonymous function)elfinder.min.js:1706 (anonymous function)jquery.js:3058 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:2676 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

The same mistake is on other actions like, cut remove and others.
When I look in script I see that mistake is in string with

```
return a.each(this.files(b), function (a, b) {
                if (!b.read || !b.phash) return !d.reject(["errCopy", b.name, "errPerm"])
            }), d.isRejected() ? d : d.resolve(c.clipboard(this.hashes(b))
```

I don't really understand why it is happening because structure isn't clear for me:

```
d = this
b = a(b)
```

and a is parameter of main function of elfinder

```
(function (a) {
```

Anyone can help me to solve the problem? May be someone met similar issue? 
**UPDATE**

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionelfinder.min.js:2860 elFinder.commands.cut.execelfinder.min.js:1746 (anonymous function)elfinder.min.js:1706 (anonymous function)jquery.js:3058 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:2676 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionelfinder.min.js:4249 elFinder.commands.rm.execelfinder.min.js:1746 (anonymous function)elfinder.min.js:1706 (anonymous function)jquery.js:3058 jQuery.event.dispatchjquery.js:2676 jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle.eventHandle
```

Comment: *"The same mistake is..."* What mistake? Looking at minimized code is probably not wise. Swap it out for the non minimized version of the library's code.

Comment: I've added mistakes which I see when I try to delete or cut. I've used tidy up function of jsfiddle. Do you know if a, b and others not informative variables are normal in not minimized func?

Comment: Now I've downloaded https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/blob/2.x/js/elFinder.js it says 
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a functionVM317 main.js:2 (anonymous function)jquery.js:974 jQuery.Callbacks.firejquery.js:1084 jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWithjquery.js:406 jQuery.extend.readyjquery.js:83 DOMContentLoaded when I try to init elFinder.

Comment: I've found that this version has not function(a){ } wrapper. May be this is a problem? But what should I write instead of a then?

Comment: It seems that you're using version 2.x-RC1. Try using a nightly buid from here: https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder#downloads. This will, most likely, solve you're issue

Comment: Well, I've included elfinder.full.js from nightly 2.x build. The same mistake.

Comment: If u write it as an answer I'll approve it it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your URL (/radio/elfinder-2.0-rc1/php/connector.php) it seems that you're using Elfinder 2.0 RC1.

You should know that Studio 42 (the company who developed elFinder) hasn't updated or developed any code for elFinder since 2012. The user [nao-pon](https://github.com/nao-pon) has been responsible for the development and bug fixes lately.

So, you should download a [Nightly build](https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder#downloads) to use the latest updated code. That should probably solve your issues.